# How do I inspect an object in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I've used the `pry` gem in the past to inspect objects in Ruby on Rails. Is there a way to do this in Laravel?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by inspecting an object?

Comment: for example I've pulled in a blog post and saved it to a `$blog` variable. How do I print out the `$blog->title`, '$blog->author` somewhere so I can see the data

Comment: have you tried `dd` in laravel? it stands for dump and die. use it like `dd($blog);`

Comment: yes! just what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PRY is more like an attempt for a REPL console..

you should be able use 'php artisan tinker' as REPl to execute and inspect objects.
Not sure if it's installed by default:
https://github.com/laravel/tinker

However inspecting / debuging on itself, you should consider xdebug, with IntelliJ IDE / PHPStorm or any other IDE supporting XDebug.

It gives you many advantages and make debugging and work more effective

Comment: as you see PRY describes itself as a REPL, https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: this is a perfect answer, thanks so much. I'm using Atom for my IDE and it looks like theres a package for xdebug, will give it a shot